# Vue 1 class binding returning always false

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am working on this [Laravel Social Network Script](https://codecanyon.net/item/socialite-laravel-social-network-script/17553328) and it uses ***Vue 1.0.26***.

My objetive is to bind the class **connected** or **disconnected** according to the user status which is **true** or **false**. I created a Laravel API to get the user status:

Controller (Laravel):

```
// $id = User id - https://www.mysite.uy/api/v1/status/{userid}
public function getUserStatus($id)
{
    $active = false;
    
    $open_session = \App\OpenSession::where('user_id', $id)->first();
    
    if($open_session) {
        if(Carbon::parse($open_session->created_at)->diffInSeconds(Carbon::parse($open_session->expires)) < 86400 && $open_session->active > 0) {
            $active = true;
        }
    }
    return response()->json($active);
}
```

This works fine from the URL, it returns **true** or **false**, but then here is some **view.blade.php**:

```
<li class="list-group-item" v-for="conversation in conversations.data" v-if="conversation.user"> <!-- Conversaciones -->
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="showChatBox(conversation)">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
                <img v-bind:src="conversation.user.avatar" alt="images">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">
                    @{{ conversation.user.name }} 
                    <i v-bind:class="getUserStatus(conversation.user.id)"></i> <!-- <-- look at here -->
                </h4>
                <span class="pull-right active-ago" v-if="message">
                    <time class="microtime" datetime="@{{ message.created_at }}" title="@{{ message.created_at }}">
                    @{{ message.created_at }}
                    </time>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </a>
</li>
```

This block is being displayed as `<i></i>` on the HTML when using the **getUserStatus()** method on **computed**:

```
<h4 class="media-heading">
    @{{ conversation.user.name }} 
    <i v-bind:class="getUserStatus(conversation.user.id)"></i> <!-- <-- look at here -->
</h4>
```

And this displays `<i class="status disconnected"></i>` even when the **response.data** is true and I check it with `console.log(response.data == true)`:

```
<h4 class="media-heading">
    @{{ conversation.user.name }} 
    <i v-bind:class="['status', getUserStatus(conversation.user.id) ? 'connected' : 'disconnected' ]"></i>
</h4>
```

And here is the Vue stuff:

```
data: {
    status: {
      on: 'connected',
      off: 'disconnected'
    },
},
created: {
    ...
},
methods: {
  getUserStatus: function(userid)
  {
    this.$http.post(base_url + 'api/v1/status/' + userid).then(function(response) {
      if(response.data == 'true') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  },
},
computed: {
  /*getUserStatus: function(userid)
  {
    this.$http.post(base_url + 'api/v1/status/' + userid).then(function(response) {
      return {
        status: true,
        connected: response.data == 'true',
        disconnected: response.data == 'false'
      }
    });
  }*/
}
```

I only have one of the methods "working", but I switch them. I am reading [this guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) but I get this is for Vue 2.

Comment: I think you should return result of the $http function.
`getUserStatus: function(userid) { return this.$http.post etc.. }`

Comment: @BelminBedak what is the difference? I tested it anyway but it makes a memory pick and causes: `uncaught exception: out of memory`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it work by adding a default variable in `data` and changing it later:

```
data: {
    ...
    userStatus: {},
}
```

And in the method. As you can see I made some irrelevant changes on the Controller side.

```
methods: {
    getUserStatus: function(userid)
    {
        var userStatus = this.$http.post(base_url + 'api/v1/status/' + userid).then(function(response) {
            this.userStatus = JSON.parse(response.data);
        });

        return this.userStatus.status;
    },
    ...
}
```

And in the HTML side I use:

```
<h4 class="media-heading">
    @{{ conversation.user.name }}
    <i class="status connected" v-bind:class="[ 'status', getUserStatus(conversation.user.id) ? 'connected' : 'disconnected' ]"></i>
</h4>
```

Now I have a different issue: The function seems to run repeteadly so the status are constantly changing. All the other functions runs once.